# How do you reference an html element in external Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to link the JavaScript file to the HTML in this specific way, but it's not working. Not interested in using jQuery for this specific question or referencing the function in html.

```js
// javascript.js
const button1 = document.querySelector(".button1");

button1.onclick = function() {
  alert("External JS file works!");
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="button1" class="button1"></input>
```

Clicking the button doesn't show the alert

Comment: Just like with inline JS, you need the DOM to be ready. Either place the `<script>` tag right before the closing `</body>` tag, or wrap your JS code with `addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { /* code goes here */ });`

Comment: Since the code you posted works as evinced by the example above, either your path to the external JS file is incorrect, or you're executing your code too early

Comment: Hm... it's so weird. I have another button and function where I make it alert via <input type="button" class="button2" onclick="button2()"/> and that works but the one in the question doesn't. So the js file is loaded and referenced properly but something else is off that I'm missing I think...